# How should I initialize linked list in C++?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have an array which I have to initialize into a list
What I try to do

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct data_t 
{
    unsigned int id_;
    char name_ [50];
};

struct node_t
{
    node_t * next_;
    data_t data_;
};

void initialize(node_t **, const char **, const unsigned int);

int main()
{
    node_t * first = NULL;
    const char * data [3] = {"Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie"};

    initialize(&first, data, 3);

    return 0;
}

void initialize(node_t ** head, const char ** data, const unsigned int n) {
    node_t * current = NULL;
    node_t * previous = NULL;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        current = new node_t;
        current->next_ = previous;
        current->data_.id_ = i+1;
        strcpy(current->data_.name_, data[i]);

        if (i == 1)
        {
            *head = previous;
            previous->next_ = current;
        } else {
            previous = current;
        }     
    }
};
```

`next_` just loops and changes between 2 values. I tried many different options but nothing works. Please help.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Think about `if (i == 1)` and what happens if `i == 2` for example (which it will be in your loop).

Comment: you are getting downvotes because you didnt supply all the code so we cant test it out

Comment: ask yourself , why am I doing something special on the second node. That `if (i == 1)` is very odd

Comment: I would consider writing a C++ linked list and not a C linked list.

Comment: @pm100 I have added the missing code

Comment: @SilverMoon17 you have added code, but what you show here [still does not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/vbGPz6z8T).

Comment: @DrewDormann now it works there

Comment: Echoing Sweenish's comment in a way, but if you are learning the  C++ languages, your educational materials seem to be pushing the C language hard. You may to [get some different materials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::string` instead of `char` arrays?

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, only char[]

Comment: One of the best ways to [grok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok) a linked list is to draw pictures. Follow the coded instructions exactly, stepping through the function with a debugger to see what really happens with your code will help a lot here, and see if you can draw the list. If you cannot, you'll know where the code went wrong and probably have a really good idea what you should have done instead.

Comment: @SilverMoon17 Ok, too bad. Anyway, I would try to break it down in smaller pieces. Make an `insert` function that inserts _one_ `data_t` into the list. You can then loop in `initialize` and call that repeatedly. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/v9xhPfYsz)

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, I've been doing this for about two hours, but nothing comes out, I kind of understand how it should work, but I can't translate it into code correctly

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have a task to do it in this function

Comment: @SilverMoon17 Sure, but are you _forbidden_ to create helper functions? If you are, you could still simplify it: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/Y9reraq74)

Comment: The way I initialize a linked list is to set the head pointer and the tail pointer to `nulptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something special in the case of 'first' vs 'not first', you knew this but had it wrong.

- On the first one (i==0) you need to set head so the caller gets the pointer to the first node
- on subsequent ones you have to set the prior ones next pointer to point at current. For the first one there is no prior

Plus you set the `current->next` to point to `previous`, thats wrong too, that made your loop

So this is what you need

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    current = new node_t;
    current->next_ = NULL; <<<======
    current->data_.id_ = i + 1;
    strcpy(current->data_.name_, data[i]);
    if (i == 0)
        *head = current;
    else
        previous->next_ = current;
    previous = current;
   
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it works, thank you, I understood my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't use `std::string`s, I suggest that you add a constructor to `data_t` that can copy the `char` array:

```cpp
struct data_t {
    data_t(unsigned id, const char* name) :
        id_{id} // can be copied automatically
    {
        // the char array needs to be copied manually:
        std::strncpy(name_, name, sizeof name_ - 1);
        name_[sizeof name_ - 1] = '\0';
    }

    unsigned int id_;
    char name_[50];
};
```

With that, your `initialize` function could be simplified to

```cpp
// last in `data`, first in the list:
void initialize(node_t*& head, const char** data, const unsigned int n) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // create a new `node_t` with `next_` pointing at the current `head`
        // `data_` will be initialized by calling the added constructor
        // assign the returned `node_t` to `head`
        head = new node_t{head, {i + 1, data[i]}};
    }
}
```

or

```cpp
// first in `data`, first in the list:
void initialize(node_t*& head, const char** data, const unsigned int n) {
    for (unsigned int i = n; i > 0; --i) {
        head = new node_t{head, {i, data[i - 1]}};
    }
}
```

Note that `initialize` takes `head` *by reference* (`&`) to make calling it simpler:

```cpp
int main() {
    node_t* first = nullptr;
    const char* data[3] = {"Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie"};

    initialize(first, data, 3); // not &first here
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xYsaeGEsc)